# Split mySQL result on comma

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mySQL table that looks like this(with some other columns I didn't select): 
[image: sql table]

I have a mysqli php query this:

```
$sql=('SELECT point FROM placemarks WHERE id < 5');
```

A result:

```
while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {

     printf ("%s <br />", $row["point"]);
```

---

```
-157.798176, 21.254402, 0

-157.804087, 21.253042, 0

-157.805289, 21.252882, 0
```

First, I want to split the result on the comma. Once I have that I want to insert the values back into the 'lat' and 'lng' columns with php and mysqli. I've searched and tried for a couple hours. At this point I'm sure I am on the completely wrong path.

Comment: What is the 0 after the 2nd comma for? Do you need it too?

Comment: The 0 is an input error. I could put it in a third column if it is a problem or I can just rebuild the table without it. Or ignore it completely. Sloppiness on my part. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to split and then manipulate in php simply to update the lat/lng in the db then you could do it in one query like this perhaps:

```
update `placemarks` set `lat`=substring_index(`point`,",",1 ), `lng`=substring_index(`point`,",",-1 );
```

damnit - never noticed or acknowledged the trailing zero

```
update `placemarks` set 
    `lat`=substring_index( substring_index(`point`,",",2 ),",",1 ),
    `lng`=substring_index( substring_index(`point`,",",2 ),",",-1 );
```

Comment: Good second effort. The lat and lng columns were different types than the point. It threw me for a second altering the numbers slightly. I saw the substring_index in my searches but hadn't tried it. The first answer skipped the lng column. @Pete some credit for noticing the trailing 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use explode and break it into array:

> The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

```
 print_r(explode(",",$row["point"]));//breaks into pieces at comma
```

Then created your desired query and put them in your database as you asked

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE placemarks 
SET lat = SUBSTRING_INDEX(point, ',', 1)
,lng =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(point, ',', -1), 1, -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In php explode maybe.

```
$point = explode(',', $row['point']);
```

Comment: The return value from explode is an array of strings. So, instead of print_r, you will assign the result to a variable. Then iterate through them, building the DML (Data Manipulation Language aka SQL) to change the row.